# How do I check if xml-rpc are working on OpenERP 7?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

I'm trying to figure out if my server is accepting or not xmlrpc request. What I know is that when I try to access `http://my_ip:8069/xmlrpc/common` or `http://my_ip:8069/xmlrpc/object`  on my browser I get a "File not found error". Is that what is expected?
**Do I have to start my server with any flag to start xml-rpc suport?**

Here is my openerp-server.conf

```
admin_passwd = my_pass
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = openerp
db_password = False
addons_path = /opt/openerp/v7/addons,/opt/openerp/v7/web/addons,/home/lfc/openerp/v7/addons
;Log settings
logfile = /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
; log_level = error
log_level = debug
```

And my starting script:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             openerp-server
# Required-Start:       $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:         $network
# Should-Stop:          $network
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Enterprise Resource Management software
# Description:          Open ERP is a complete ERP and CRM software.
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp-server
NAME=openerp-server
DESC=openerp-server

# Specify the user name (Default: openerp).
USER=openerp

# Specify an alternate config file (Default: /etc/openerp-server.conf).
CONFIGFILE="/etc/openerp-server.conf"

# pidfile
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid

# Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.
DAEMON_OPTS="-c $CONFIGFILE"
# Added option to debug
#DAEMON_OPTS="-c $CONFIGFILE --debug --log-level=debug"

# Log File
LOGFILE=/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log


[ -x $DAEMON ] || exit 0
[ -f $CONFIGFILE ] || exit 0

checkpid() {
    [ -f $PIDFILE ] || return 1
    pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
    [ -d /proc/$pid ] && return 0
    return 1
}

case "${1}" in
        start)
                #Check if deamon is already running
                checkpid
                if [ "$pid" != "" ]; then
                        echo "$NAME already running with pid $pid."
                else
                #Only starts if not running
                echo -n "Starting ${DESC}: "
                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
                        --chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
                        --exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS} --logfile=${LOGFILE}

                echo "${NAME}, OK."
                fi
                ;;

        stop)
                echo -n "Stopping ${DESC}: "

                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
                        --oknodo

                #Check existence of PID file. If exists, then remove it
                checkpid
                if [ "$pid" != "" ]; then
                `rm ${PIDFILE}`
                echo -n "${PIDFILE} removed "
                fi

                echo "${NAME}, Stoped!"
                ;;

        restart|force-reload)
                echo -n "Restarting ${DESC}: "

                start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
                        --oknodo
                echo -n "\n${NAME}: STOPPED"
                sleep 1


                #Check existence of PID file. If exists, then remove it
                checkpid
                if [ "$pid" != "" ]; then
                `rm ${PIDFILE}`
                echo -n "\n${PIDFILE} REMOVED "
                fi
                sleep 1

                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
                        --chuid ${USER} --background --make-pidfile \
                        --exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS}

                echo "\n${NAME}: STARTED\n"
                ;;

        *)
                N=/etc/init.d/${NAME}
                echo "Usage: ${NAME} {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
                exit 1
                ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access it with valid data.

Common (`xmlrpc/common`) is for connection purposes and Object (`xmlrpc/object`) is to access tables and functions (modules).

For that you can create an api using Python, PHP, Java, etc

For example check this [link](https://doc.openerp.com/6.1/developer/12_api/)

Comment: But you say there is no need to any adicional flag in my openerp-server.conf.  
My question is because I tried to test my module with Apache JMeter following these instruction (http://selvam4u.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/load-testing-openerp-with-jmeter/) and I keep getting Error 500. When I tried to access with the browser I got 404, so I was wondering if I wasn't doing anything wrong...

Comment: The xml code from that tutorial had an error, after correcting it, it all went fine!

Comment: @FilipeCastanheira add correct code here as answer so others will also   use

Comment: I didn't change anything on the code from http://selvam4u.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/load-testing-openerp-with-jmeter/ except that for some reason copy-pasting it to JMeter "ate" a space in the xml declaration and that was why I was getting the Error 500. Changing `<?xmlversion="1.0"?>` to `<?xml version="1.0"?>` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To check it You may use [openerp-proxy](https://github.com/katyukha/openerp-proxy) project, which can be used as lib or CLI client to OpenERP / Odoo using xml-rpc or json-rpc.

So to test your connection:

```
$ pip install openerp_proxy  # also install IPython if you like it
$ openerp_proxy   # this will openen python/IPython shell
>>> db = session.connect()     # This will ask you required info for connection
>>> db.registered_objects      # this should return list of registered Openerp/Odoo models
```

Hope this will help