# Open ERP : http://myipaddres/xmlrpc returns 404 Not found

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm unable to activate xmlrpc function on OpenERP, When I try to request http://my.ip.addres/xmlrpc returns a "404 not found" Error.

I'm using it on ubuntu. Installed by apt-get.
Here is my  /etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf  file

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = 127.0.0.1
db_port = False
db_user = openerp
db_password = openerp

xmlrpc = True
xmlrpc_port = 8069
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use socket connection to access data via xmlrpc

Check  this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493087/how-do-i-check-if-xml-rpc-are-working-on-openerp-7)